# OpenCV 4.8.1 Segmentation Fault using findContours()

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to find and draw contours on frames from the webcam. I'm getting this error:
`segmentation fault`

**The error occurs when calling the findContours() function.** Everything before that call works fine (grayscale and threshold). I tried similar code in Python and it worked fine, but the problem occurs when running in C++. I've read that this is a common mistake when working in C++.

## Code

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0, cv::CAP_V4L);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open camera." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the width and height
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);

    // Check if the settings were applied successfully
    double width = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    double height = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

    // std::cout << "Width: " << width << ", Height: " << height << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        cv::Mat image;
        if (!cap.read(image)) {
            std::cerr << "Error: Could not read frame from the camera." << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        // convert image to grayscale format
        cv::Mat img_gray;
        cv::cvtColor(image, img_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        
        // apply binary treshholding
        cv::Mat thresh;
        cv::threshold(img_gray, thresh, 150, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
        
        // detect the contours on the binary image using cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
        std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
        cv::findContours(thresh, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        // draw contours on the original image
        cv::Mat image_copy = image.clone();
        cv::drawContours(image_copy, contours, -1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);

        // Display the actual frame (image)
        cv::imshow("Webcam", image_copy);

        // Break the loop if the 'ESC' key is pressed
        if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

`g++ -o main.o main.cpp -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc`

## System

- Ubuntu 22.04 (x86_64)
- OpenCV 4.8.1
- Driver Version: 545.23.08
- CUDA Version: 12.3
- GCC/G++ Version: 11.4.0

## OpenCV Build

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
         -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
         -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
         -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
         -D WITH_TBB=ON \
         -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
         -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON \
         -D NVCUVID_FAST_MATH=ON \
         -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON \
         -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON \
         -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF \
         -D BUILD_ZLIB=ON \
         -D BUILD_TIFF=ON \
         -D WITH_GTK=ON \
         -D WITH_NVCUVID=ON \
         -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
         -D WITH_1394=ON \
         -D BUILD_PROTOBUF=ON \
         -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
         -D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv4.pc \
         -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=OFF \
         -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
         -D WITH_V4L=ON \
         -D WITH_QT=ON \
         -D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
         -DBUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF \
         -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
         -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
         -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Comment: can you reproduce that *without* the video access, just from a single image file, or even a Mat of all zero?

Comment: I have tested it with both an image, and a cv::Mat object. Segmentation Fault still occurs. Here I provide the [code](https://github.com/estradavg/processing_tracker/blob/opencv4_cpp/testFiles/testFindContours_img/main.cpp). (*or* https://github.com/estradavg/processing_tracker/blob/opencv4_cpp/testFiles/testFindContours_img/main.cpp) @ChristophRackwitz